# how to get a parentNode's index i using d3.js

Tags: dom, d3.js

Using d3.js, were I after (say) some value x of a parent node, I'd use:

```
d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().x
```

What I'd like, though, is the data (ie datum's) index. Suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The index of an element is only well-defined within a collection. When you're selecting just a single element, there's no collection and the notion of an index is not really defined. You could, for example, create a number of `g` elements and then apply different operations to different (overlapping) subsets. Any individual `g` element would have several indices, depending on the subset you consider.

In order to do what you're trying to achieve, you would have to keep a reference to the specific selection that you want to use. Having this and something that identifies the element, you can then do something like this.

```
var value = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().x;
var index = -1;
selection.each(function(d, i) { if(d.x == value) index = i; });
```

This relies on having an attribute that uniquely identifies the element.

If you have only one selection, you could simply save the index as another data attribute and access it later.

```
var gs = d3.selectAll("g").data(data).append("g")
  .each(function(d, i) { d.index = i; });
var something = gs.append(...);
something.each(function() {
  d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().index;
});
```

Comment: Hey Lars, do you think the following would work (I haven't tried this)? `var index = selection.data().indexOf(d3.select(this.parentNode).datum())`?

Comment: Turns out `var index = selection.data().indexOf(d3.select(this.parentNode).datum())` does the job nicely. Thanks to both of you :-)

Comment: selection.data().indexOf(d3.select(this.parentNode).datum()) in fact works only for the immediate parent. In fairness to others, I feel obliged to unaccept the answer.

Comment: Sorry, is that not what you were asking for?

Comment: Just a minor note. The second approach in this answer only works if the original datum is an object rather than a simple number. If your dataset is just an array of numbers, you can convert it to an array of objects first by using the JavaScript `map()` method.